# Delete related Schema on Mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to delete the relation between schemas.
Having two Schemas:

Checklists and Tasks

Each Tasks are related with one Checklist

Removing one task we need to remove the the task and the relation between task and the checklist, the problem is the last )`:

The schemas:

```
const checklistSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {type: String, required: true},
    tasks: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Task'
    }]
})

const taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {type: String,  required: true},
    done : {type: Boolean, required: false},
    checklist: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Checklist",
        required: true
    }
})
```

The code to remove:

```
let task = await Task.findByIdAndDelete(task_id) //Removing the task
let checklist = await Checklist.findById(task.checklist)
let taskToRemove = checklist.tasks.indexOf(task.id)

/* The code to remove the relation checklist-task */

await checklist.save()
```

Anyone knows how delete this relation? Thanksssss

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to define tasks attribute in the checklist schema. You already have related between them as each task has the checklist it belongs to, so that if you want to get the tasks that belongs to a checklist you can do it through a query

Comment: Oook, that's genial! Thanks!